# Only one Apache Solr to search into Multiple/Cross-domain CMSs?

Tags: search, solr, cms, cross-domain

Is it possible for single-instance of Solr to use across multiple Applications, Cross Domains? Like multiple CMSs such as Wordpress + Joomla + Drupal. Any searching from anywhere should be showing the Results from all of connected applications.

For example:
If i search a word `marketing` from the Wordpress Site, it should output the results from Wordpress itself and also the contents from the Joomla and Drupal sites.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you've just got to make sure the indexing for all the different sites cooperate to provide compatible search data.  Exactly how you'll achieve that is a tricky subject that would be better suited to SO (since it's a programming question).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Is there any example you know for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in your case that makes it much different from a "single domain" setup.
Solr works as REST service, so in order to index content, all you have to do is provide access from different domains. For bulk import (e.g. from a db or csv) we use [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

If you want to [facet](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) on domain-bases (narrow down search results by one or more domains using check boxes, after results are already displayed) and you have e.g. an article entity that you want to index, on top of its regular attributes (Solr fields like Body, Author, Date, ...) you should add additional one that would represent its domain.

To setup security (who can see a document) I'd use [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html), which knows how to work with Solr out-of-the-box.

If you're just starting with Solr I suggest you first go through [this tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/doc-files/tutorial.html), which is a great starting point to grasp Solr (and general search engine) concepts.